# Translating mongoid to german

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I got a problem to translate the default validation messages in mongoid. 
I create a /config/initializers/mongoid.rb with

- Mongoid.add_language("de")

http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/languages.html

But every call on a validated field i got translation errors:

- translation missing: de.mongoid.errors.models.comment.attributes.body.too_short
- translation missing: de.mongoid.errors.models.user.attributes.username.blank

I have

- Ruy on Rails 3.2
- Ruby 1.9.3
- mongoid 2.4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check on Mongoid source, the de.yml locale file you can see this two key are not translate :

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/2.4.0-stable/lib/config/locales/de.yml

You can do some pull_request on Mongoid 2.4.0-stable branch to add it.

Comment: Biig thx ("i dit to wondering why one or two translations worked correctly :D ^^")

Comment: the `too_short` key in even not in english locale. The blank is maybe an mistake/forget. Durran live in Berlin now.