# devise password does not match translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, translation

Hello I need to translate devise password does not match to spanish, but I can't find what is the original text in English and I just see this:

Password confirmation translation missing: es.mongoid.errors.models.user.attributes.password_confirmation.confirmation

So I suppose that I need a translation, any help please.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Devise, but I have worked with i18n translations in Rails. If you can find the Devise English (en) yaml file(s), then I think I can help you eliminate translation errors in the Devise component.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826032/translating-mongoid-to-german

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to this gem
https://github.com/tigrish/devise-i18n it can solve your problem